# My code works on JSfiddle but not on dreamveaver nor browser?

Tags: html, jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/8hn5kgpw/156/
this is the link on JSfiddle, it works fine.

below is the code I have for dreamveaver, but It dosen't work, seems it couldn't call the script.js file. but not sure why.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>lab1</title>
<script type= "text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
First name:
<input type="text" id="newfruit">
<br>

<h1> Fruit Shelf:</h1>

<div id="div1">
    <ol id="fruits"></ol>
</div>

<h1>Basket:</h1>

<ol id="basket"></ol>
<input type='button' onclick='changeText2()' value='Submit' />
</body>
</html>
```

here is the javascript file

```
var list = document.getElementById('basket');
var fruitsshelf = document.getElementById("fruits");
var fruitslist = ["pear", "apple", "peach", "grapes", "strawberry", "melon"];
for (var j = 0; j < fruitslist.length; j++) {
    var newlist = document.createElement('li');
    newlist.id = 'listid'+j;
    newlist.appendChild(document.createTextNode(fruitslist[j]));
    fruitsshelf.appendChild(newlist);
}

function changeText2() {
    var newfruit = document.getElementById('newfruit').value;
    var entry = document.createElement('li');
    var len = fruitslist.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (fruitslist[i] == newfruit) {

            entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(newfruit));
            list.appendChild(entry);
            document.getElementById("listid"+i).remove();
            delete fruitslist[i];
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you double-checked that the script.js file is in the same folder as your HTML file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put your JavaScript at the end of the page or wrap it in a window onload event (which is what jsFiddle does by default). The way you have it now, you're trying to execute JavaScript on elements that don't yet exist. Your fiddle is loading the code before the closing body element, which your example above is not.

Move `<script type= "text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>` to be before `</body>`.